# SonarAnalyzer Java Rules

Tags: java, sonarqube, rules

With reference to the below link

http://www.sonarqube.org/sonarqube-java-analyzer-the-only-rule-engine-you-need/

is there any documentation on what rules from Findbugs, Checkstyle and pmd are already covered in SonarQube SonarAnalyzer for Java?

When I compare Findbugs and Sonar Way using SonarQube compare quality profile, it is not showing any common rules between both the profiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not going to see any overlap via the SonarQube interface because the rule engines use different titles and different implementations.

You can get the "what's covered" information from the SonarSource RSpec (Rule Specification) Repository for [FindBugs](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/RSPEC-3066?jql=project%20%3D%20RSPEC%20AND%20resolution%20%3D%20Unresolved%20AND%20type%20!%3D%20Language-Specification%20AND%20%22Covered%20Languages%22%20%3D%20Java%20AND%20FindBugs%20is%20not%20EMPTY), [Checkstyle](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/RSPEC-3052?jql=project%20%3D%20RSPEC%20AND%20resolution%20%3D%20Unresolved%20AND%20type%20!%3D%20Language-Specification%20AND%20%22Covered%20Languages%22%20%3D%20Java%20AND%20Checkstyle%20is%20not%20EMPTY), and [PMD](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/RSPEC-3027?jql=project%20%3D%20RSPEC%20AND%20resolution%20%3D%20Unresolved%20AND%20type%20!%3D%20Language-Specification%20AND%20%22Covered%20Languages%22%20%3D%20Java%20AND%20PMD%20is%20not%20EMPTY)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. It helped me a lot and could get what i want.

Comment: Then perhaps you'd care to [accept] the answer @Ramki? :-)

Comment: why 42 Checkstyle rules are rejected in Sonar Analyzer? For example, Import Order, Empty Line Separator, etc? Will they not be implemented in Sonar Analyzer? If we want to use these rules, do we need to install the Checkstyle plugin and add the rules to our profile?

Comment: Nope, no plan to implement "rejected" rules; we just don't see the value in them.